# how to delete a single value using delete button in a calculator app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an Android Calculator App. I want to delete an input instead of clearing the whole value.
This is code for adding values

```
private void updateText(String value) {
        output = output + value;
        display.setText(output);
    }
```

How can I delete a single value using the delete button?**strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private String removeLastChar(@NonNull  String value){
  return value.substring(0,value.length()-1);
}
```

Note: Input value must non-null. So check before passing